# I accidentally, deleted table of a model in db.sqlite (manually). How can I recreate it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-migrations

**I accidentally, deleted table of a model in db.sqlite**. **How can I recreate it?**
When I run command 'python manage.py makemigrations' it works but when I run'python manage.py migrate' it says 'No migrations to apply'

Answer (score 1):

Figure out which app and migration originally created the table. For example, if the model that created the table is in an app called `users` in the initial migration #0001, you can run this command to dump the SQL that created the table:

```sql
$ python manage.py sqlmigrate users 0001
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model User
--
CREATE TABLE "users_user" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL, "last_login" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, "is_superuser" boolean NOT NULL, "username" varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL, "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL, "email" varchar(75) NOT NULL, "is_staff" boolean NOT NULL, "is_active" boolean NOT NULL, "date_joined" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, "subscriber_code" varchar(255) NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX "users_user_username_06e46fe6_like" ON "users_user" ("username" varchar_pattern_ops);
COMMIT;
```

After that, you can open a database shell in SQLite, and run the SQL via copy and paste:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

Good luck with your restore!

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the old db.sqlite3 and recreat a new one, also delete the migration files.
after that creat a new migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and appy them to the new empty db.sqlite3

```
python manage.py migrate
```

don't forget to use python3 instead of python if you are on mac.

Answer (score 0):

Delete migration files and re-run `python manage.py makemigrations`